# Подскажите пожалуйста, как в атрибут сохранить экземпляр класса?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в атрибут сохранить экземпляр класса?

Comment: `self.attr = MyClass()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом примере создается экземпляр класса MyClass с атрибутом value, а затем создается второй экземпляр. Этот второй экземпляр сохраняется в атрибуте my_attribute первого экземпляра. Вы можете обращаться к значениям атрибутов экземпляра через точку, как показано в последней строке кода.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

# Создаем экземпляры класса
instance_of_class = MyClass(42)
another_instance = MyClass(123)

# Сохраняем экземпляр класса в атрибуте
instance_of_class.my_attribute = another_instance

# Печать значения атрибута
print(instance_of_class.my_attribute.value)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое